# sending string with & sign in ajax jquery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am using inline editing in my form's text area where it works as it should be , but when the text are string contains & sign it is only saving up to the & sign. so how can i url encode in javascript the & sign so my php scripts gets it and save in mysql as & again.
this is my current code and desc is the string that might contain & sign occasionally

```
    var field_userid = $(this).attr("id") ;
    var desc = $(this).val() ;      

    $.post('includes/update-property-modal.php' , field_userid + "=" + desc, function(data){    });
```

Comment: have you tried setting `processData` to false?

Comment: I think you should try with [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to get the values to send in Ajax.

Comment: send data as this => `{field_userid: desc}`

Comment: @LShetty -> on the right track, however because `field_userId` is a variable, your recommendation would not work OOTB ... it would set the value of the property `field_userId` instead of that variable's value. That is why in my answer i assigned it as I have, to allow for variable property names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it the way you are currently do it, you need to encode it.

```
$.post('includes/update-property-modal.php' , field_userid + "=" + encodeURIComponent(desc), function(data){    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use an object?

```
var self = this,
    params = {};

params[self.id] = self.value;

$.post('includes/update-property-modal.php',params,function(data){
    // whatever thine wish may be
});
```

This should manage the existence of the '&' internally, and really is the better way to send parameters with `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use encodeURIComponent() to escape all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, _ - . ~ ! * ' ( )

```
$.post('includes/update-property-modal.php', field_userid + "=" + encodeURIComponent(desc), function(data) {});
```

But in the case of jQuery's ajax() and your example, it is better to use it this way:

```
var params = {
  $(this).attr('id'): $(this).val()
};
$.post('includes/update-property-modal.php', params, function(data) {});
```